# The provided payload cannot be decrypted because it was not protected with this protection provider on the /connect/endsession/callback

Tags: c#, .net-core, identityserver4, asp.net-core-3.1

There is a .net core 3.0 web application with IdentityServe4 inside. Application is hosted on Azure Web farm.
In logs, I found the few exceptions with the message:

> Exception reading protected message - The provided payload cannot be decrypted because it was not protected with this protection provider.

RequestPath: `/connect/endsession/callback`

Stack trace:

```
System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException:
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.KeyRingBasedDataProtector.UnprotectCore 
(Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection, Version=3.1.8.0, Culture=neutral, 
PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.KeyRingBasedDataProtector.DangerousUnprotect 
(Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection, Version=3.1.8.0, Culture=neutral, 
PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.KeyRingBasedDataProtector.Unprotect 
(Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection, Version=3.1.8.0, Culture=neutral, 
PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
at IdentityServer4.Stores.ProtectedDataMessageStore`1.ReadAsync (IdentityServer4, Version=3.1.3.0, 
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=f294d0afe402bb2b)
```

Data Protection settings:

```
services.AddDataProtection()
        .PersistKeysToAzureBlobStorage(container, keyStorage.Path)
        .ProtectKeysWithAzureKeyVault(client, keyEncryption.KeyIdentifier)
```

Recently, we have added `services.AddOidcStateDataFormatterCache(schemes);` with `SQL Distributed` cache implementation.

Does someone know why this exception happens and how to fix it?

Comment: Error indicates the client and server (including certificate) are not using the same encryption algorithm (and settings) so the server is not able to validate the key. Does code work if you removed the recent enhancement?  Five years ago the industry eliminated TLS 1.0/1.1 due to security  issues and require TLS 1.2/1.3 to be used.  In June Microsoft pushed a security update which disabled TLS 1.0/1.1 on servers. I have not seen your exception before so I'm not sure if your changes are causing the exception or the exception is due to client using TLS 1.0/1.1 and server refusing the connection.

Comment: thanks for your reply, good assumption. The problem is the code is working I can't reproduce it. But I see it Application Insight logs from time to time.

Comment: Any idea how long before error occurs.  Does log file should when the request was started?  See : https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/560dc2a9-43e1-4c68-830c-6e1defe2f72d/azure-web-app-request-timeout-issue?forum=WAVirtualMachinesforWindows

Answer (score 0):

Could be that the code that creates the Data Protection API keys was changed?
Do you have many applications using the same key ring storage?

I just blogged about how to work with the data protection API and how to store the key ring in Azure Key Vault here:

[Storing the ASP.NET Core Data Protection Key Ring in Azure Key Vault](https://www.edument.se/en/blog/post/storing-the-asp-net-core-data-protection-key-ring-in-azure-key-vault)

Comment: I have only one application which is webfarm.  Are there any caveats? Btw, Good article, thanks. Would be useful if you briefly write about key rotation and specific of using in WebFarm (of course, if there are some)

Comment: Yes, there are several issues, for example https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/26786